# Seeking Guidance on Understanding Chainpoint-js

Tags: node.js, npm, block

Was wondering if anyone has used this before and has any information they could tell me about it?

I've read through the documentation and they dont seem to say a lot on its implamentation, I have gone and added to an apache server but it still seems to do nothing, I think i might be doing somethin wrong

Comment: This is probably a bit too broad of a question to have much success here. If you are still having trouble after reading documentation, I recommend starting to research blog articles, online videos, and other such resources to help get you started!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.